# How to pass a argument from one function to the another function onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments, addeventlistener

I want  to pass an argument onclick from one function to the another function

Suppose,

> Html

```
<button class='btn1' onclick='passvalue(2)'>
<button class='btn2' onclick='getvalue()'>
```

when I will click on `btn1`, 2 value will pass from `passvalue()` to `getvalue()`.  And then,  Whenever i will click on `btn2` only, `getvalue()` will print 2 on console.

But I couldn't able to do it.I hope my problem is enough clear to understand. Please someone help me to do that.

Comment: What is `onlick`?

Comment: What should `getvalue()` (or more generally, clicks on btn2) do when btn1 has not been clicked before (and `passValue` has not been called)?

Comment: It just a typing mistake.It will be `onclick`

Comment: If `passvalue` has not been called, then `getvalue` will give a alert message!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the best solution, but it should work for you.

This for HTML

```
<button onclick="firstFunc(2)">first</button> 
<button onclick="secondFunc()">second</button>
```

And this for JS

```
let val

function firstFunc(x){
    val = x
}
function secondFunc(){
    console.log(val)
}
```

And here is it in [JsFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/OndrejHj04/t1ch2jp0/1/)

Comment: Thank you.. it solve my problem a lot!